# Baseball Tickets - VB - Not computing the correct price?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

```
Public Class Form1
Dim intTicketChoice As Integer
Dim finalCost As Decimal
Dim cost As Decimal
Dim seatType As Integer


Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)
End Sub

Private Sub cboTypeOfTicket_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cboTypeOfTicket.SelectedIndexChanged

    intTicketChoice = Me.cboTypeOfTicket.SelectedIndex
    Me.ListBox1.Items.Clear()
    EnableObjects()

    Select Case intTicketChoice
        Case 0
            SingleGame(seatType)
        Case 1
            Season(seatType)
    End Select
End Sub

Sub EnableObjects()
    lblNumTickets.Visible = True
    txtNumOfTickets.Visible = True
    lblSeatType.Visible = True
    ListBox1.Visible = True
    lblAnswerText.Visible = False
    lblCost.Visible = False
    btnClear.Visible = True
    btnCompute.Visible = True
End Sub

Private Sub SingleGame(ByVal seatType As Integer)

    Me.ListBox1.Items.Add("Box Seats $55")
    Me.ListBox1.Items.Add("Lower Deck Seats $35")
    Me.ListBox1.Items.Add("Upper Deck Seats $25")
    Me.ListBox1.Items.Add("Standing Room Only $15")


    If ListBox1.SelectedItem = "Box Seats $55" Then
        seatType = 0
    ElseIf ListBox1.SelectedItem = "Lower Deck Seats $35" Then
        seatType = 1
    ElseIf ListBox1.SelectedItem = "Upper Deck Seats $25" Then
        seatType = 2
    ElseIf ListBox1.SelectedItem = "Standing Room Only $15" Then
        seatType = 3
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub Season(ByVal seatType As Integer)

    Me.ListBox1.Items.Add("Box Seats $2500")
    Me.ListBox1.Items.Add("Lower Deck Seats $1500")


    If ListBox1.SelectedItem = "Box Seats $2500" Then
        seatType = 4
    Elseif ListBox1.SelectedItem = "Lower Deck Seats $1500" Then
        seatType = 5
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub btnCompute_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCompute.Click
    Dim ticketNum As Integer

    ticketNum = Convert.ToInt32(txtNumOfTickets.Text)
    intTicketChoice = cboTypeOfTicket.SelectedIndex

    Dim totalCost As Decimal = GetGameCost(ticketNum)


    Try
        ticketNum = Convert.ToInt32(txtNumOfTickets.Text)
    Catch Exception As FormatException
        MsgBox("Number of tickets must be numeric")
        Return

    End Try


    'Display cost:
    lblAnswerText.Visible = True
    Me.lblCost.Text = totalCost.ToString("C")
    lblCost.Visible = True


End Sub

Private Function GetGameCost(ByVal ticketNum As Integer)

    If seatType = 0 Then
        finalCost = (ticketNum * 55D)
    ElseIf seatType = 1 Then
        finalCost = (ticketNum * 35D)
    ElseIf seatType = 2 Then
        finalCost = (ticketNum * 25D)
    ElseIf seatType = 3 Then
        finalCost = (ticketNum * 15D)
    ElseIf seatType = 4 Then
        finalCost = (ticketNum * 2500D)
    ElseIf seatType = 5 Then
        finalCost = (ticketNum * 1500D)
    End If
    Return finalCost
End Function
```

End Class

Hi guys, I'm stuck on my VB homework.  I'm new at this so don't rip me to shreds, hehe.  Anyways, Every time I try to compute, it seems to give me 55 * ticketnum instead of look for the actual seatType and use that one.  I saw another question on here about this same problem, but couldn't find an answer to my exact question.

Any ideas or tips?

Answer (score 0):

We're not going to rip you to shreds, it's actually a joy to get a homework question where the poster has actually *done* something rather than dump the assignment question here verbatim, expecting to be spoon-fed :-)

In this case, I'd be looking at the fact that you pass `seatType` to both `SingleGame` and `Season` by *value.*

That means any changes are only going to be made to the local copy, not the object variable. The object variable will remain at its initial value of zero so that, when you come to calculate the price, it always does the multiply by 55.

Either pass by reference so that changes are reflected back to the object variable, or just use the object variable itself (by not passing it as a parameter at all).

Comment: I replaced the byVal with byRef's and I still have the same problem.  I decided to just delete the byref's and val's and I'm thinking there should be a Me.seatType somewhere maybe? but I'm not sure where... Thanks a TON for your help btw!